# Do I need to first install ASP.NET 5 on a server to deploy a website?

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core

I want to install my asp.net 5 website on a windows server 2012 box (IIS).  From what I understand, asp.net 5 is self-contained and is deployed via the Publish function of Visual Studio 2015. And, thus doesn't need to be separately installed on the target server..

Is this correct?

Comment: yes i think so, it contains all the files in publish which are needed to run the asp.net core application

Comment: Deploy asp.net 5 is a real pain. Im trying for 2 days and still nothing. Thats really frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS configuration is [documented](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html). You need to install the [IIS Platform Handler](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/httpplatformhandler), as IIS doesn't understand the new way to start apps without it.

After that publish will do everything you need.

Comment: Make sure you add "app.UseIISPlatformHandler();" in the Configure method in your startup class - that's not listed in that documentation but I believe needs to be part of your pipeline. Its in the standard template, but just in case you have removed it/started from scratch.